# Call tabelize again after injecting table with ajax and jquery html

Tags: jquery

I'm using this plugin, [tabelizer](https://github.com/powerconsulting/jquery.tabelizer), it is very simple to use, you just construct your table as specified and on document ready you call tabelizer:

My jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    tabilize();
});
```

My function:

```
function tabilize(){
    console.log("It's getting called");
    var table1 = $('#table1').tabelize({
        /*onRowClick : function(){
            alert('test');
        }*/
        fullRowClickable : false,
        onReady : function(){

        },
        onBeforeRowClick :  function(){

        },
        onAfterRowClick :  function(){

        },
    });
}
```

And I get the desired result,

But when I refresh my table with an ajax call:

```
success: function (response) {
       var resp = response.split('|');
        if (resp[0] == 'ok'){
                $('#table1').html(resp[1]).promise().done(function(){
                   tabilize();
                });
                return false;
```

I know it is getting called again because when I load my page, I get the the console log and when I click the button I get the console log again.

I know the table its the same plus the new row because the same function creates the table, also, if I just refresh my browser it gets tabelized, but when I called with the refresh table button it doesn't get tabelized.

I noticed the reason for this was that you can only call tabelize once, if I don't call it on document ready, and I click my refresh table button, the table does get tabelized, but if I hit refresh it again, it doesn't get tabelized, I just get the table.

So, what do I need to do to be able to call tabelize again?

Comment: Have you considered using a more appropriate plug-in that can better handle changes to table data?

Comment: I most certainly have not, but when I looked at this one I liked it, it's very simple to use, you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if anyone stumbles across this same problem, what I did was modify jquery.tabelizer.min.js and added a function I called retabelize, which just inits itself again and returns the public object.

I know it has something to do with the object created by the plugin itself being persistent, and once initialized it doesn't init itself again, it just updates, so when you call tabelize again, it doesn't init itself again which is what you need.

The plugin is very short itself, so you can read what it does.

What I added to  the script:

```
e.fn.retabelize = function() {
    return n.caller = this,
    n.init(),
    n.updateData(),
    n.getPublicObj()
}
```

And my tabelize function:

```
function tabilize(){

if (table1 == null || table1 == 'undefined'){
    table1 = $('#table1').tabelize({
    /*onRowClick : function(){
        alert('test');
    }*/
    fullRowClickable : false,
    onReady : function(){

    },
    onBeforeRowClick :  function(){

    },
    onAfterRowClick :  function(){

    },
});
}else{
    table1 = $('#table1').retabelize();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.fn.tabelize = function(confProp){
    var existingSelf = this.data('tabelizer');
    if (typeof existingSelf == 'undefined'){
        $.extend(self.conf, confProp);
        self.caller = this;
        self.init();

    }else{
        self = existingSelf;
        $.extend(self.conf, confProp);
        self.caller = this;
        self.init();
    }
    //Store copy of self in data for repeat calls, update it after any repeating call
    self.updateData();

    return self.getPublicObj()
};
```

My tabilize function

```
function tabilize(){
            alert("table value"+table1);
            table1 = $('#table1').tabelize({
                /*onRowClick : function(){
                    alert('test');
                }*/
                fullRowClickable : true,
                onReady : function(){
                    console.log('ready');
                },
                onBeforeRowClick :  function(){
                    console.log('onBeforeRowClick');
                },
                onAfterRowClick :  function(){
                    console.log('onAfterRowClick');
                },
            });
    }
```

then call given method to any where    `tabilize();`

Comment: Dear, Pierre, What u do not get ?